# Changes ggplot Legend gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

I have this data set about average growth rate of different genotypes:

```
Genotype  desv  mean  Rank
   <fct>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
  ENG2    0.345  4.29     7
  ENG20   0.255  3.90     9
  ENG22   0.185  4.19     8
  ENG24   0.341  3.84    10
  ENG25   0.195  3.51    12
  ENG3    0.267  4.38     6
  ENG32   0.262  3.61    11
  ENG4    0.223  4.49     4
  ENG5    0.359  5.13     2
  ENG7    0.122  4.49     5
  ENG8    0.182  4.90     3
  ENG9    0.459  5.28     1
```

And the code bellow to make a ggplot graph:

```
ggplot(growth2)+
  geom_col(aes(x=Rank, y=mean, fill=mean), width=0.7, color="Black")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=Rank, ymin=mean-desv, ymax=mean+desv), position = position_dodge(width=0.9),width=0.4, alpha=1)+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust =2, vjust = 0.5, family="sans", size=12, color="Black"))+
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank())+
  xlab("")+
  ylab(expression(paste("AGR (cm "," ", year^-1,")", sep="")))+
  theme(axis.line.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(family="sans", size=12, color="Black"))+
  theme(axis.title.y= element_text(margin=margin(t=0, r=10, b=0, l=0)))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), limits = c(0,6))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="green", name="")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color="Black")+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.5,1), legend.direction = "horizontal")+
  theme(legend.text = element_blank())+
  theme(plot.margin = margin(1,0,0,0, unit = "cm"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),labels = c("ENG 9 ", "ENG 5 ", "ENG 8 ", "ENG 4 ", "ENG 7 ", "ENG 3 ", "ENG 2 ", "ENG 22", "ENG 20", "ENG 24", "ENG 32", "ENG 25"))
```

However my legend is not the way I want. Green part (high growth rate) should be on the left. I try the reverse in guides_legend but it did not work.
Also I would like that the size of the legend occupies the length of the graph. I did not find any argumented in ggplot about legend lenght.

Could someone help me? Or indicate if it is possible make these legend changes.

[image: Differences in growth rate among genotypes for the highest growht (green) to lowest growth (red)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of a gradient scale you have to make use of `guide_colorbar(reverse = TRUE)` instead of `guide_legend`:

The with of the colorbar could be set via option `barwidth = grid::unit(750, "pt"))`

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(growth2) +
  geom_col(aes(x = Rank, y = mean, fill = mean), width = 0.7, color = "Black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = Rank, ymin = mean - desv, ymax = mean + desv), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), width = 0.4, alpha = 1) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 2, vjust = 0.5, family = "sans", size = 12, color = "Black")) +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab(expression(paste("AGR (cm ", " ", year^-1, ")", sep = ""))) +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(family = "sans", size = 12, color = "Black")) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0))) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green", name = "", guide = guide_colorbar(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "Black") +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 1), legend.direction = "horizontal") +
  theme(legend.text = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(1, 0, 0, 0, unit = "cm")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), labels = c("ENG 9 ", "ENG 5 ", "ENG 8 ", "ENG 4 ", "ENG 7 ", "ENG 3 ", "ENG 2 ", "ENG 22", "ENG 20", "ENG 24", "ENG 32", "ENG 25"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To switch the order of colors in the legend, I swapped the color names on this line:

```
  scale_fill_gradient(low="green", high="red", name="")+
```

To widen the legend across the whole x-axis, I used `legend.key.width` after your `theme()`:

```
theme(plot.margin = margin(1,0,0,0, unit = "cm"),
    legend.key.width= unit(4, 'cm'))+
```